# WSO2 CEP horizontal scalability

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I'm investigating of the new **WSO2CEP** and **WSO2 STREAM PROCESSOR** products and I would like some information:

1. I would know if it can manage the scalability in a configuration where I have multiple instances installed in cluster on multiple servers, and each instance share the same information (rules, events, streams, etc ...)
2. Is it possible to aggregate the events across the servers? For example given the rule "select * from my_stream.window(10 minutes) having count = 2" and server 1 receives the first event and server 2 the second, validating the condition and firing an associated action only one time (not for each server/instance)
3. Is it possible to aggregate the events across the servers using `pattern`
   where condition?

Answer (score -1):

I could answer it only for WSO2SP

> I would know if it can manage the scalability in a configuration where I have multiple instances installed in cluster on multiple servers, and each instance share the same information (rules, events, streams, etc ...)

indeed, yo ucan have a manager(s) node and all worker nodes will synchronize the apps (rules, streams, ..) from the manager node

For other questions - the state (aggregated values) can be [persisted](https://docs.wso2.com/display/SP400/Configuring+Database+and+File+System+State+Persistence) across the cluster, so it should work